# Mysql Database design for sale reports

Tags: database-design

So I am stuck with this decision of how to design my database for this sales reporting.

Here is the scenario. I have 100K+ users with each conducting 0 or more sales each day. If s/he has 0 sales then nothing gets stored for that user that day otherwise if s/he has more than one sale then it justs gets incremented by 1 for that day.

Now the question is about database design (with focus on eventual performance). One easy way of doing it would be to just create one table with date, and user_id and use WHERE clause to get weekly, monthly and yearly sale performance of a given user.

```
Table: user_sales_counter
--------------------
user_id, sales, date
```

However, the problem I see here is that if after six months, I'd want to look up a particular week's report of a user then I would have to traverse through 18 million records in worst-case scenario.

So the exact question I wanted to ask is that could I create further three tables for weekly, monthly, and yearly record keeping which will allow me to do two things, I could delete daily sales data, say older than 2 months, and still I'd have access to a user's weekly, monthly etc sales record because the purging of these tables can be set at, e.g 1 year or older.

```
Table: weekly_sales_counter
---------------------------
week_no, month_no_year, user_id, sales

Table: monthly_sales_counter
----------------------------
month_no_year, user_id, sales

Table: yearly_sales_counter
---------------------------
year, user_id, sales
```

I am using Redis to even further minimize reads to these tables.

The drawback I see with this approach is that instead of one, I'd have to run 4 queries to log a single sale counter as each table's counter would have to be incremented separately.

What would be the best scenario to go about it? Single table or the second one? Or do you have another approach in mind that I could take?

Thanks

Comment: The single table seems like the right approach to me

Comment: Thanks for the answer but could explain why? And, what would be the problem with multi table approach?

Comment: You're solving a problem (that doesn't exist), by creating unnecessary redundancy

Comment: Fair enough. But let's say it does exist, what should be the approach then?

Comment: 18 million records, with proper indexing and data types, shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Summary tables are common solutions for reporting tasks - datawarehouses work this way. Wether you need such tables depends on the performance gain for reports vs the additional resources needed to keep these summary tables updated. We cannot tell which is the better solution for you. You need to test it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience, querying from million data of transaction will need more and more longer time. my suggestion is:

1. create one table to keep smallest unit of period that you want to use in the future.
2. create crontab or trigger or anything to count sales and grouping by user id on that table, you can count it on the end of the day, or the end of the week, try and find the best way.
3. whenever you want to show that counter, you can just select from that table, grouping by the user id again, it will be lighter than count on the transaction table.